# append wordpress post title with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, title

i want add the title `<?php the_title(); ?>` after my selector by jquery

```
('a img').after('<span>the title here</span>');
```

Comment: it display all titles after every img

Comment: thanks Dominic 
great idea but after img i found <span></span> with out any content in it

Answer (score 1):

PHP code is interpreted on the server, jQuery code in the browser (long after the PHP interpreter has finished). They can't really see each other.

What you can do is put the value of `the_title()` in some element on the page and then use jQuery to locate it and add it:

```
var title = $('#the_title').text();
$('a img').after('<span>' + title + '</span>');
```

[EDIT] If you have several titles, then you must map them to the images somehow. There are many possible ways to do that:

- You can send the name of the image to the PHP server, have it look up the title and send that back. Look up `$().json()`.
- You can put all the titles in some piece of HTML that you make invisible by wrapping it in `<div style="display: none;">`. In your jQuery, you can then map images to titles.

Comment: Or add the title to a javascript variable directly, set before the jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

What Aaron said.

But maybe using a custom data attribute so (so it validates in HTML5).

In your PHP:

```
<img data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" src="..." />
```

—

In javascript (jQuery):

```
$('a img').each(function(){
   var title = $(this).attr("data-title");
   $(this).after('<span>' + title + '</span>');
});
```

—

<strike>Untested but that's the idea.</strike> Tested.

Comment: I had a mistake in the code. I just tested it and it's now corrected. Apologies.
If it's making an empty span with nothing in it, then it's likely to be an issue with the_title. The_title returns the title of the post/page and must run inside the loop — is that what you're trying to do?