# Asking JQuery to Display the Title of the Current Page in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, navigation

I have a mobile drop-down/selector menu in my responsive Wordpress theme and I'd like the default displayed option to always be the current page title. I've found where to change the default text (currently 'Menu'), but I don't know how to make it be the current page title.

This post seems to have a similar problem, but I can't seem to adapt it to my situation, as I'm a beginnger to JQuery > ([append wordpress post title with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257944/append-wordpress-post-title-with-jquery))

Here's my code. I want to put something like `<?php the_title(); ?>` where it currently says Menu, but I know PHP and JQuery don't talk to each other.

```
    $nav_params = array(
    'text' => __('Menu','wpex'),
);
wp_localize_script( 'wpex-responsive', 'responsiveLocalize', $nav_params );
```

.

This is my workaround since I can't figure out how to have the selector automatically be tuned to the current page in the menu, without any "default" 'Menu' or other option at the top of the menu. I could share more code if anybody has advice with that instead.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: write <input type="hidden" value="<?php the_title(); ?>" ID="hiddenTitle"/> then write jQuery to append hiddenTitle to any element HTML or value.

Answer (score 0):

The article title is in some heading element, right?

```
var myTitle = $('h1.myHeadingClass').text();

$nav_params = array(
    'text' => __(myTitle,'wpex'),
);
wp_localize_script( 'wpex-responsive', 'responsiveLocalize', $nav_params );
```

If that isn't an option for whatever reason, do like the other answer suggested and place the title in a hidden element that you can grab later:

```
<div id="myTitle" style="position: absolute; left: -999em;" aria-hidden="true">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</div>

var myTitle = $('#myTitle').text();
...
```